# Any way to restrict the use of @@version in SQL Server for some users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

According to me it is not something that is possible, but in my work they tell me that I need to restrict the use of @@version for certain users
I searched and found nothing to help me. Does anyone have an idea if it's possible?

Comment: Can you define "restrict"? Do you want to reduce the information it exposes? Do you want them to not be able to call it all? What exactly is the concern? Because it may be information they can get from other sources even if there were a way to block `@@VERSION`.

Comment: You're right, I just found that there are other ways to get to the same information.

But for now I just want the @@version command to not be called. Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you *want* to restrict a `LOGIN` from using `@@VERSION`? "Because my work tells me" isn't a reason. This is most certainly an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: I could see, maybe, "we are using Developer Edition in production and don't want our users to know" :-)

Comment: Thank you, I think that with all this it will be clear that what they ask for is something unnecessary.
Maybe my suggestions like that SQL injection should be treated differently will be considered viable :´)

Comment: Why do you want to restrict it? Typically users don't connect to production databases directly, but apps do it for them.

Comment: SQL Injection and `@@VERSION` *literally* have no relationship. It would be like saying that having a way to stop a passenger choose the radio station in your car lowers the chance of your car being stolen.

Comment: @ThomA I think they're saying that they can raise the priority of investigating SQL injection if they can get their colleagues to stop worrying about access to `@@VERSION`.

Comment: That would make more sense, @AaronBertrand . :)